# UserStoreConfigAdminService Issue

Tags: api, wso2, store

Went thru the following steps but getting issue reaching the UserStoreConfigAdminService?wsdl

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Calling+Admin+Services

Getting the following error:

The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/UserStoreConfigAdminService/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

Also it says the service is available in 
osgi in the list of AdminServices

Is there issues using this with Identity Server 5.8?
Missing a step?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Managing User Stores with APIs
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/managing-user-stores-with-apis/ 
Open the deployment.toml file in the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf directory and set the admin_service.wsdl element to false.
[admin_service.wsdl]
enable = "false"
2. Restart WSO2 Identity Server.
3. If you have started WSO2 Identity Server in default configurations, use the following URL in your browser to see the WSDL of the admin service: https://localhost:9443/services/UserStoreConfigAdminService?wsdl.

Comment: And got the EPR issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IS 5.8.0 pack then you need to,

1. Change the value of the configuration '' to false in carbon.xml
2. Restart the server
3. Use the following URL to access the WSDL file.

https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl

If you re using IS 5.9.0 please refer to the document [1].
What you need to do is,

1. Open the deployment.toml file in the /repository/conf directory and add the admin_service.WSDL element and set it to false as below.

> [admin_service.wsdl] enable = "false"

2. Restart WSO2 Identity Server.
3. Use the following URL to access the WSDL file.

https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/managing-user-stores-with-apis/